# Trying to leave a comment should never fail a review audit

Tags: bug, comments, review-audits

I just failed a review audit because I tried to leave a comment on a high quality question.  This is wrong: leaving a comment should never cause a review failure. The presumption that adding a comment to a high quality post could not result in an eventual improvement of the post is wrong.

Comment: I completely agree.