# Comments on First Posts / Late Answers should not count as reviews

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, comments, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

#### Proposal: Comments on First Posts / Late Answers should not count as reviews

Note I'm not suggesting *they should pass them either*, they should simply not be a review action.  This would alleviate the confusion people have surrounding commenting during audits, and I cannot see a good reason to keep comments as a part of the review system. I don't believe the system should be handling situations where it can't largely tell if you did "the right thing" or not.

#### Impact:

This would basically remove the need for anyone ever to post about failing a review audit, and would allow people who've learned not to comment because of the audits to be able to leave useful comments.  On the flip side this may enable individuals who would have not left useful comments to leave bad ones, however since presumably the option would be taken away entirely, they still have to click through to the question in order to do this, so they would at least learn at that point that a corrective comment on a good question was the wrong choice.  Additionally, leaving a comment would no longer on its own be seen as a corrective action on audits, leaving only flagging or down-voting, however I believe if you were going to leave a comment as a corrective action, then you probably wanted to down-vote/flag anyway.

#### Alternatives

At least one other alternative was mentioned in other discussions, [automatically passing reviews when commenting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377929/an-attempt-to-comment-should-pass-audits-regardless-of-known-good-or-known-bad).  I don't feel this is the correct course of action to take because it introduces at least one other complication into the system. Abusing by leaving comments on every post and never failing audits. Robo reviewers are the very thing audits are meant to protect against, and I feel robo reviewing is a bigger problem than an individual paying enough attention to question to leave a comment, but then posting poor comments.

#### Context

Over the years we've gotten quite a bit of people confused over the fact that commenting in First Posts and Late Answer queues result in people failing audits.  People are quite surprised to find that, no matter the validity of the comment, because comments are considered review actions, on good questions cause one to fail the audit. Apparently, the inclusion of comments themselves in the system was [debated early on](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260810/2036035), but as we can see the consequences of adding them into the review systems as purely corrective means a lot of confusion.

Examples:

[Commenting on "First Post" review test always leads to a penalty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361862/commenting-on-first-post-review-test-always-leads-to-a-penalty)

[Failed audit for making a valid comment?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277551/failed-audit-for-making-a-valid-comment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Why does commenting cause me to fail a review audit?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262919/why-does-commenting-cause-me-to-fail-a-review-audit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[First post review audit failed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327092/first-post-review-audit-failed?rq=1)

[Trying to leave a comment should never fail a review audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318398/trying-to-leave-a-comment-should-never-fail-a-review-audit?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Leaving a comment is considered as a "negative" review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268866/leaving-a-comment-is-considered-as-a-negative-review?noredirect=1&lq=1)

#### Related discussion

[Review audit failed after just clicking "add comment"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Use of comments while reviewing on an audit question from Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377884/use-of-comments-while-reviewing-on-an-audit-question-from-stack-overflow)

Comment: I support this idea, as it removes the extrinsic motivation for commenting while still allowing it. Regarding the alternative: never failing audits is livable; it's already possible to detect & pass audits with a trivial amount of work, and if someone is reviewing badly and doing this they'll eventually get banned manually. But the implication there is that commenting - as a stand-alone action - is desirable... And that's a tougher sell, particularly in [these dark times](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377438/how-can-the-example-unwelcoming-comments-be-improved/377439#377439).

Answer (score 15):

Comments are one of, if not the, most useful course of action for most posts a reviewer sees in either of those queues.  Sure *some* are going to merit a flag for deletion, and some won't merit any action at all, a few will only have problems that the reviewer can fix themselves with an edit, but most will have *some* ways that they could be improved, but that require the author to be involved, which means commenting on how the author can make the posts better.

In fact I'd go so far as to say that there's not much point of those queues even *existing* if commenting isn't a part of them.  That's how core the feature is to those queues doing their job.

Now yes, it's true that the automated audits don't really have a good mechanism for telling whether a person commenting on an audit post is actually a good audit.  But don't let that ruin the entire queue and take away one of the most important features of it.